# Graceful disabling of LTM pool members

Tags: f5, icontrol

Does anyone know the API command to gracefully disable pool members such that

1) Any new session is prevented by redirecting to a different member (server) on the pool.

2) Existing sessions aren't disconnected.

I have a pool of 5 servers and I would like to make API call such that only active sessions are kept, and no new sessions are initiated.

So far I tried sending the following in my PUT request body
{state:"user-up", session:"user-disabled"}

But it looks like LTM still allows new connection to be there. I cannot seem to find the valid configuration values which I can put for `state` and `session`.

Could someone help me?
Regards

Answer (score -1):

the mapping from GUI to REST for the appropriate pool member states is documented [in this article](https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/icontrol-rest-working-with-pool-members) on DevCentral. To be clear, the disabled state in the GUI is the graceful way to allow existing sessions but not new sessions, and that is in REST `{"state": "unchecked", "session": "user-disabled"}`